# is len() a function or method in python?

Tags: python

In the context of object oriented programming, a function is different from a method.

when i examine the help doc, this piece of code

```
?len
```

outputs

```
Signature: len(obj, /)
Docstring: Return the number of items in a container.
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
```

does this imply that len() could be function or method depends on concrete  situation?

Comment: It is a function that can delegate to the `__len__` method of classes. It doesn't have the implication you suggest, though.

Comment: In my book, a method is part of a set of functions that can be called by an object instance, e.g. `bark` in `dog.bark()`. In that sense, `len()` is a function. Maybe others can confirm/reject this interpretation.

Comment: @BramVanroy would you plz provide the whole name of your book?

Comment: Where do you read this help doc? It looks incorrect.

Comment: Python just doesn't have separate types for builtin functions and builtin methods.

Comment: @shi95 It's a figure of speech, I don't have an actual book.

Answer (score 3):

There's one builtin `len` ***function***. You use it like `len(obj)`. Each object can implements its own `__len__` method to override what `len()` will return; `len` the function invokes `__len__` the method.

If any object chooses to also implement a `len` method, it may do that, but that has nothing to do with the `len` function or `__len__` convention.

`builtin_function_or_method` just means that the manual doesn't specifically distinguish between these two things and lumps them all into the same type.

Answer (score 2):

`len()` Is a function, while there is `__len__()` that is method.

read [Here](http://www.trytoprogram.com/python-programming/python-built-in-functions/len/) for more information.