# Is abs() a function or method?

Tags: python

Is `abs()` a function or method?
I tried searching on Google for an answer but half of what I found said it's a function and the other half said it's a method.

Comment: What's the difference between a function and a method for you?

Comment: I'd say: A method is a function that's bound to an object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is len() a function or method in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56168023/is-len-a-function-or-method-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

`abs` is a built-in function, as specified when you run help:

```
>>> help(abs)
Help on built-in function abs in module builtins:

abs(x, /)
  Return the absolute value of the argument.
```

Comment: Also, in the [official docs for Built-in _functions_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs)

Comment: You can compare it with `help(str.lower)` or `help('somestring'.lower)`.

Comment: Confusingly, `str.lower`'s repr says `<method 'lower' of 'str' objects>`, and `"foo".lower` says `<function str.lower()>` — the opposite of what you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

Function. The method is something associated with an object/class. Functions are pieces of code not bound to any particular object/class type.

abs(), if I remember correctly, is in the script named - builtin.py which in Python is called a Module.
So abs() is a function.

Here is a link to more builtin functions:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Comment: You can actually google this instead of posting here on SO. all over the internet you find abs() function mentioned.